Write a setup.cfg installation key to install dependencies from other installation keys
The Problem:
I'm writing a setup.cfg file for a Python package that requires different sets of dependencies depending on what it's used for. For development purposes, I want to add a key to the [options.extras_require] table of the setup.cfg file that installs multiple sets of dependencies simultaneously.
The relevant section of the setup.cfg file at the moment:
[options.extras_require]
option1 =
    pkg1
    pkg2
    pkg3
    pkg4
    pkg5
option2 =
    pkg1
    pkg2
    pkg6
    pkg7
    pkg8
option3 =
    pkg3
    pkg4
    pkg9
    pkg10
all = 
    pkg1
    pkg2
    pkg3
    pkg4
    pkg5
    pkg6
    pkg7
    pkg8
    pkg9
    pkg10

The accompanying setup.py file is minimally dressed, and all our metadata is currently still kept in the setup.cfg file:
from __future__ import annotations

import setuptools

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Do not add any parameters here. Edit setup.cfg instead.
    setuptools.setup()

So far, I've added the dependencies manually to the all key, but this would require me to manually crawl through and add dependencies to it every time the package's list of dependencies changes.
Is there a way to write the all key such that it will install everything listed under options 1, 2, and 3 without the need for me to manually write them to all each time the environment changes?
BUILD:
The Python version I'm testing for at the moment is 3.11.8, and I'm using setuptools 68.2.2 along with pip 23.3.1. The package is supposed to work from Python 3.9 and up, so it will need to be compatible with multiple versions of setuptools and pip.
UPDATE:
Feeding Modified Dictionary to setup():
I tried tinkering with the setup.py file as suggested below, and it now looks like this:
from __future__ import annotations

from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.config.setupcfg import read_configuration

# Run code only if file is run as a script
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Read the configuration from setup.cfg
    config = read_configuration("setup.cfg")

    # Get the dependencies from the other sections
    option1_deps = config["options"]["extras_require"]["option1"]
    option2_deps = config["options"]["extras_require"]["option2"]
    option3_deps = config["options"]["extras_require"]["option3"]

    # Combine dependencies
    all_deps = option1_deps + option2_deps + option3_deps

    # Update the config with the combined dependences
    config["options"]["extras_require"]["all"] = all_deps

    # Pass the udpated configuration to setuptools.setup()
    setup(**config["options"])

However, I then ran into the following issue when trying to run pip install -e .[all]:
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error in setup command: 'python_requires' must be a string containing valid version specifiers; 'SpecifierSet' object has no attribute 'split'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.

Testing read_configuration() and setup() individually:
After some investigation, I found that read_configuration works as advertised, and is able to generate the dictionary structure for the [metadata] and [options] tables correctly. However, when that is fed into setup() it causes it to be unable to read the setup.cfg correctly afterwards. Running setup() without any arguments works just fine.
How should I proceed from here?

Please post the code you're using to read / parse the config. But the answer is yes, you could have conditions to run both.

Hi @Dan, thanks for asking for further information. If I've understood you, correctly, I have amended my initial question to include the contents of the setup.py file. It really is just a dummy file, and setuptools.setup reads the required dependencies from setup.cfg instead.

TL;DR
There are several ways to achieve this goal. The best practice is to manage the Python project with pyproject.toml, and there are also some simpler workarounds.
Workarounds
A straightforward solution is to replace pip install '.[all]' with pip install '.[purpose1, purpose2]'. In this case, dependencies from both groups are installed.
If you still want to install all dependencies just through pip install '.[all]', you should parse the setup.cfg file and merge them manually:
from __future__ import annotations

from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.config.setupcfg import read_configuration

# Run code only if file is run as a script
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Read the configuration from setup.cfg
    config = read_configuration("setup.cfg")

    # Get the dependencies from the other sections
    option1_deps = config["options"]["extras_require"]["option1"]
    option2_deps = config["options"]["extras_require"]["option2"]
    option3_deps = config["options"]["extras_require"]["option3"]

    # Combine dependencies
    all_deps = option1_deps + option2_deps + option3_deps

    # Update the config with the combined dependences
    config["options"]["extras_require"]["all"] = all_deps

    # Pass the udpated configuration to setuptools.setup()
    setup(**config["options"])

Notice that since the read_configuration is deprecated as an exposed main API, the read_configuration should be imported from setuptools.config.setupcfg instead of setuptools.config. (According to the warning message, this may also be deprecated in the future, so it's recommended to migrate from setup.cfg to pyproject.toml.)
(I'm not sure why there's an error about specifier though. It looks right for me.)
A Better (but not Perfect) Way
NOTICE: There are still some unsolved problems (see Discussion) in this section and I'm looking for a solution.
If anybody has ideas about this, don't hesitate to tell me!
A modern way to build a Python package is proposed in PEP 517, in which the setup.cfg is suggested to be replaced with pyproject.toml.
In your case, the options.extras_require and options.python_requires should be equivalent to this in pyproject.toml:
[project]
requires-python = ">=3.9"

[project.optional-dependencies]
purpose1 = [
    "pkg1",
    ...,
    "pkg5"
]
purpose2 = [
    "pkg1",
    ...,
    "pkg8"
]
all = [
    "__ALL_DEPS__"
]

Then you can combine both groups like this:
import tomllib                                                                                                                                                                                                        
from copy import deepcopy                                                                                                                                                                                             
from setuptools import setup                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
# Run code only if file is run as a script                                                                                                                                                                            
if __name__ == "__main__":                                                                                                                                                                                            
    # Read the configuration from pyproject.toml                                                                                                                                                                      
    with open('pyproject.toml', 'rb') as fcfg:                                                                                                                                                                        
        config = tomllib.load(fcfg)                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    # Get the dependencies from the other sections                                                                                                                                                                    
    option1_deps = config["project"]["optional-dependencies"]["option1"]                                                                                                                                              
    option2_deps = config["project"]["optional-dependencies"]["option2"]                                                                                                                                              
    option3_deps = config["project"]["optional-dependencies"]["option3"]                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    # Combine dependencies                                                                                                                                                                                            
    all_deps = option1_deps + option2_deps + option3_deps                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    # Construct dependencies mapping                                                                                                                                                                                  
    extras_require = deepcopy(config["project"]["optional-dependencies"])                                                                                                                                             
    extras_require["all"] = all_deps                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    # Pass the updated configuration to setuptools.setup()                                                                                                                                                            
    setup(extras_require=extras_require)

Discussion
There're still some problems with this code.
I cannot figure out why the dependencies are not installed even if I pass extras_require to the setup method.
Maybe this is because the extra dependencies in the pyproject.toml overrides the setup arguments.
If this is the cause, the modified config should be written back to pyproject.toml:
with open('pyproject.toml', 'r') as fcfg:
    contents = fcfg.read()
deps_string = '\n'.join([f'"{dep}",' for dep in all_deps])
with open('pyproject.toml', 'w') as fcfg:
    fcfg.write(contents.replace('"__ALL_DEPS__"', deps_string)

Apparently this is not the perfect solution, but it should work in this case.
Conclusion
In summary, the main idea to achieve this is to parse the config file and manually combine the parts.
No matter which config format is used, the core is to parse the config file, merge the dependency groups, and apply the merged dependencies.
The above solutions may still need to be improved, and I will update this answer when I find a suitable approach.

Hi there, thank you so much for your advice on how to address this matter. I've tried implementing your solution of tinkering with setup.py, but ran into issues with read_configuration being unable to parse through the config file properly. I've included the issues in my original question. Further input and advice would be much appreciated!

That being said, pip install -e .[option1,option2,etc] does work as advised, so that's good, at least!

It seems like a compatability issue. I'll look into this soon and look for some workarounds.

Thanks, I really appreciate it. I've added the versions of python, setuptools, and pip that I'm working with in this current test environment. The package is meant to work on Python environments 3.9 through to 3.11, so I will be redoing the installation multiple times on those different environments.

I tried to locate the problem, but it doesn't seem to be an error with the setup.cfg file. So I came up with another possible solution using pyproject.toml, which probably works for you.

Thank you so much for continuing to look into this matter for me. It's much appreciated! It is strange, because without tinkering with the setup() function, the setup.cfg can be read and used properly for the installation!
At my current level of understanding, it seems to be due to a difference with how read_configuration() parses the file compared to the sub-functions used in setup(). Do correct me if I'm wrong!
Thanks for the alternate pyproject.toml suggestion. I will have a look at that as well and let you know how that goes.

It seems that the function internally used by setup() is distutils.dist.parse_config_files, maybe you can try this one to replace the read_configuration.

Thanks for your suggestion to try using distutils.dist.parse_config_files directly. I got an ImportError when I tried to do so, sadly. ImportError: cannot import name 'parse_config_files' from 'distutils.dist'. I've also had the opportunity to test the read_configuration function by itself, and that one works perfectly fine. The error seems to arise from when I feed the dictionary generated by read_configuration back into setup(). The added input prevents it from reading the rest of the setup.cfg file correctly, for some reason. Any further thoughts on this matter?
